# Node.js Stylus Interpolation is not rendering the styles as show in docs

Tags: css, node.js, mixins, stylus

I'm trying to run a vendor specific css mixin with stylus and I took this straight from the docs, but It doesn't seem to be rendering the css at all.  Any thoughts?

```
vendor(prop, args)
  -webkit-{prop} args
     -moz-{prop} args
      -ms-{prop} args
       -o-{prop} args
          {prop} args

border-radius()
  vendor('border-radius', arguments)

li
 border-radius 3px 3px 0 0
```

Should be working but when the stylesheet is rendered there's not border-radius property?

Also, doing just the mixin is working properly

```
border-radius()
  -webkit-border-radius arguments
  -moz-border-radius arguments
  -ms-border-radius arguments
  -o-border-radius arguments
  border-radius arguments

li
  border-radius 3px
```

Renders:

```
li{
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px
  -moz-border-radius: 3px
  -ms-border-radius: 3px
  -o-border-radius: 3px
  border-radius: 3px
}
```

As expected.  Any thoughts on this?

Thanks

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question, I'd recommend checking out [nib](https://github.com/visionmedia/nib). Among other things, it solves this vendor prefix problem in a reusable way.

Answer (score 3):

Hey I figured this out and thought I would post back the answer.  What was tripping me up was that the mixin vendor(prop, args) were indented thus it was not rendering the code. Watch the indents!

```
vendor(prop, args)
  -webkit-{prop} args
     -moz-{prop} args
      -ms-{prop} args
       -o-{prop} args
          {prop} args
```

Should be:

```
vendor(prop, args)
  -webkit-{prop} args
  -moz-{prop} args
  -ms-{prop} args
  -o-{prop} args
  {prop} args
```